# How to build Neural Network with value type in input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I need NN that use as input parameter a street name. I have more than 10000 streets in a dataset.

All examples that I have found says if you have 3 streats you can do 3 input nodes for each streat and use 0 or 1 as values. I don't think that having more than 10000 inputs is a good idea.

What is the best solution for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more information? What is the neural net attempting to classify?

Comment: For example: I have street name, house style and want to predict house price. It is just an example, I atempt to undestand what I need to do for manage value parameter in NN that could be in many states.

Comment: Why do you think having more than 10,000 inputs is a bad idea? You could offset this high-dimensional input layer by having it feed into a small first layer of (e.g.) 5 neurons. Say you compress the input somehow, e.g. binary encoding means you would need 14 input nodes because 2^14 ~ 16,000. Your network will struggle to relate streets to prices. The network will view input node #1 as the most significant bit of the encoded-street and will need to learn the complex relationship between this input node and the price. With one-hot encoding, this relationship becomes a simple linear map.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we'd expect house prices in the same areas to be correlated to each other. So put a grid over the map, and assign each street a grid square.